# Node and Javascript: How to Programmatically Access and Cycle Through Files in a Folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder with this structure:

```
folder
  |--file1.csv
  |--file2.csv
  |--file3.csv
  |--file4.csv
```

**Is there a way to programmatically write a script to go into a folder and open one file at a time to do something and then open the next until all files in that folder has been inspected?**

Comment: One *after* the other or all at the same time? I'm asking cos file operations are asynchronous.

Comment: one after the other

Comment: [node fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) with [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: node would by default be async

Comment: Have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html - especially readdir and readdirSync and readfile and readfileSync

Comment: can node fs be used without knowing the file name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use node `fs.*Sync()` methods which will block until the operation is done.

The `readdirSync` function will give you a list of files (and subdirectories, which are also files) in a directory and `statSync` will tell you, if it's a directory or a file.

You should be aware that your script can do nothing else while doing the blocking operations though. So do not export and use that code as a function in a bigger application.

If you want to reuse it, you should write your code in an asynchronous fashion (i.e. use callbacks and handle your state / values accordingly). Or use one of the npm modules that implement the necessary functionality ("walk" seems to be a good search keyword for your use-case).

Comment: using Sync methods can be a really bad idea because it doesnt just block the current request on the server, it blocks all the request to the server